# Series expansion logic

Tags: sequences-and-series

How can I simplify $t=\frac{(k+2)}{k! +(k+1)!+(k+2)!}$? 
I've tried it but the book takes $k!$
common from the denominator. I have no idea how to simplify factorial expressions. Any help regarding simplification of such factorial related splifications will be appreciated. 
Where $!$ stands for factorial.

Comment: The numerator is probably $(k+2)!$, not $(k+2)$ as written in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$k!$ means $1 \times 2 \times 3 \times ... \times k$.

So $(k+1)!$ means $1 \times 2 \times 3 \times ... \times k \times (k+1)=k!(k+1)$

and $(k+2)!$ means $1 \times 2 \times 3 \times ... \times k \times (k+1) \times (k+2)=k!(k+1)(k+2)$

Your denominator is therefore $k!+k!(k+1)+k!(k+1)(k+2)$

Can you factorise that and take it from there?

Comment: you made it crystal clear. Thanks and your answer has been accepted and upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{(k+2)}{k! +(k+1)!+(k+2)!}=\frac {k+2}{k!(1+(k+1)+(k+1)(k+2))}\\
=\frac{k+2}{k!(k^2+4k+4)}\\
=\frac {k+2}{k!(k+2)^2}\\
=\frac 1{k!(k+2)}\\
=\frac {k+1}{(k+2)!}$$